# How to use Flutter's BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to create an alarm app in Flutter. I managed to make a workable alarm in Android, using `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val isPlaying = true;
        val startServiceIntent = Intent(context, MediaPlayerService::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("isPlaying", "true") // Pass the isPlaying value here
        }
}
```

I am using a `Service` in order to start/stop the alarm sound:

```
class MediaPlayerService : Service() {

    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)
        print("CREATED MEDIA PLAYER")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)
        mediaPlayer!!.start()
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer!!.stop()
        mediaPlayer!!.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to recreate this functionality in flutter using `flutter_broadcast_receiver` but I am not sure how to do it, the documentation does not provide a good example/explanation