# Flutter: No implementation found for method SET_SERVICE_DATA on channel FSE_APP_CHANNEL_NAME (service called from AndroidAlarmManager callback)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make an alarm app in flutter.
I am trying to recreate this [functionality written for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993181/how-to-use-flutters-broadcastreceiver):
I have this button that triggers the alarm:

```
FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                trigger();
                DateTime time = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 11));
                final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: 9));
                await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
                  const Duration(seconds: 5),
                  // Ensure we have a unique alarm ID.
                  Random().nextInt(pow(2, 31) as int),
                  callback,
                  exact: true,
                  wakeup: true,
                );
                await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
                    0,
                    'scheduled title',
                    'scheduled body',
                    now,
                    const NotificationDetails(
                        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                            'full screen channel id', 'full screen channel name',
                            channelDescription: 'full screen channel description',
                            priority: Priority.high,
                            onlyAlertOnce: false,
                            importance: Importance.high,
                            playSound: false,
                            // sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('slow_spring_board'),
                            fullScreenIntent: true)),
                    androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
                    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
                    UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);

                // await audioPlayer.play(AssetSource("audio/song.mp3"));
              },

              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              heroTag: null,
              child: const Text("RING NOW", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),

 Future<void> callback() async {
    try {
      SharedUploadData sharedUploadData = SharedUploadData();
      var result = await AppClient.execute(sharedUploadData);
      var resultData = SharedUploadData.fromJson(result);
    } on PlatformException catch (e, stacktrace) {
      print(e);
      print(stacktrace);
    }
  }

class SharedUploadData extends ServiceData {

  bool isPlaying = false;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  int progress = 0;

  Future<void> playAudio() async{
    await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"));
  }

  Future<void> stopAudio() async{
    await audioPlayer.stop();
  }

  @override
  String get notificationTitle => 'uploading';

  @override
  String get notificationDescription => 'progress -> $progress';

  String toJson() {
    var map = {
      'isPlaying': isPlaying,
      'progress': progress,
    };
    return jsonEncode(map);
  }

  static SharedUploadData fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SharedUploadData()
      ..isPlaying = json['isPlaying'] as bool
      ..progress = json['progress'] as int;
  }

}
```

main.dart service:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
serviceMain() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ServiceClient.setExecutionCallback((initialData) async {
    var serviceData = SharedUploadData.fromJson(initialData);
    if(serviceData.isPlaying)
      await ServiceClient.stopService();
    else{
      serviceData.isPlaying = true;
      serviceData.playAudio();
      await ServiceClient.update(serviceData);
    }
  });
```

The notification will wake up the app and `androidAlarmManager` is set to trigger the callback that is supposed to call the service that handles audio play/stop.

The problem is that when I call the service from `callback` i get error:  `E/flutter (15167): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method SET_SERVICE_DATA on channel FSE_APP_CHANNEL_NAME)`